# SQL - subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update all `creditCounts` except for the first (lowest) account number, however I keep receiving this error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Here is the query:

```
update Recog
set livesCount = 0
where RECID in (select 
                    r.empNumber, r.acctNbr, r.creditCount, r.groupAcctNumber, r.groupType
                from 
                    Recog r
                where 
                    creditCount > 0 
                    and policyNbr in 
                        (
                            (Select acctNbr from Recog)
                            except 
                            (Select MIN(acctNbr) 
                             from Recog 
                             Group By groupAcctNumber, groupType)
                            )
                        )
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You're saying `Where RECID in...` and then giving it 5 fields. You can only select ONE when doing `in`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error states, you are SELECTing multiple columns in the subquery and it only makes sense to select one...

```
update Recog
    set livesCount = 0
    where RECID in (
    select r.RECID
    from Recog r
          where creditCount > 0 and
          policyNbr in ((Select acctNbr from Recog)
          except (Select MIN(acctNbr) from Recog Group By groupAcctNumber,groupType)))
```

To drive it home, imagine what your statement would look like if you substituted column data in place of your subselect...

```
update Recog
    set livesCount = 0
    where RECID in (1, 'Account 123', 12, 'Group 123', 'Type X') -- Makes no sense
```